# Android Studio BuildVariants

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, android-resources, android-build-flavors

Here is my problem. I have an app which is working fine. I want the same app to have two different package name and drawable folders. So here is what i did,

```
productFlavors {
    AppOne {
        applicationId 'com.AppOne'//Package name for AppOne
    }
    AppTwo{
        applicationId 'com.AppTwo'//Package name for AppTwo
    }
}
```

Then i created two different folder inside my src. The project structure looks something like this,

```
src
   -> AppOne
          ->drawable
                    ->Image for AppOne
   -> AppTwo
          ->drawable
                    ->Image for AppTwo
   -> UnchangedApp
          ->drawable
                    ->Image for someImage
```

As far as i understand when i take the build from Flavor AppTwo the "Image for AppTwo" will be used(If i am not wrong).
This also worked fine with seperate package names and seperate icons.
The problem is that i have a local html file inside my raw folder. And i refer this in code like this

```
Webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/mytemplate.html");
```

The html file will also change for both the apps.So i created the raw folder for both the flavors. Now the project structure is like this

```
src
   -> AppOne
          ->drawable
                    ->Image for AppOne
          ->raw
                    ->mytemplate.html
   -> AppTwo
          ->drawable
                    ->Image for AppTwo
          ->raw
                    ->mytemplate.html
   -> UnchangedApp
          ->drawable
                    ->Image for someImage
          ->raw
                    ->sometemplate.html
```

Now when i run my app with flavor 1 or flavor 2, i am getting an error on webview like could not find file:///android_res/raw/mytemplate.html.

What mistake am i doing. The icons in the drawable folder are changing but the html file in raw is not. Can anyone help. Any help  would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure does not follow the convention android studio assumes. Your project structure should be like this.

`app/src/your_flavor/java` which contains your java source code

`app/src/your_flavor/res` which contains your app resources, and under this `res` directory, you can have your normal resource directories such as `drawable` `layout` `raw`, etc.

Comment: you are right. But my java files won't change. Only my resume folder changes..Is it necessary that I should have the java folder in each of the flavors?

Comment: I think you don't need... you can add only the res folder

Comment: @GuilhermeP that is what I have done. Can you please read the question and help me with an answer

Comment: @Guilherme is right. It is because android studio will merge anything you have in your `main` source set into each variant, so if you don't have any flavor-specific codes, you can "inherit" those from your `src/main` source set including `manifest.xml` file, that is why you don't want to have 2 same named classes in `main` source set and your variants

Comment: @Dummy OK. Then I have the same html file name in src/main. But I have different htmls with the same name in desperate raw folders of the flavors. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: How are you reading the raw file? do you do `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resource_id)` ?

Comment: @user5894930 it's not clearing looking at your question that you have a `res` folder for each flavor and how you access the file. You might want to update your question with exact line of code you try to access raw file.

Comment: @Sharj I will update my question with the way I am reading html from raw Sharj. But Webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/mytemplate.html"); ,this is enough to load template in webview right. Please tell me if this is not the proper way.